# Mocking a custom service in angular.js

Tags: testing, angularjs

Let's say I have a module -moduleX, that exposes a service (called serviceX).
I have another module - moduleY, itself exposing a service called serviceY that uses serviceX.

How can I test moduleY by injecting a mocked serviceX ?
NgMock does not appear to let you do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far the best I could find is to do this:

```
describe "a test" ,->
  beforeEach () ->
    mockModule = angular.module "mockModule",[]
    mockModule.factory "serviceY", [()->
        return "your mocked module" 
    ]
    angular.mock.module 'moduleX', "mockModule"
```

then whenever you inject serviceY, the new service will be used (appearently services with the same name override eachother so that the last one added wins)

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you.